# SSL offloading for multiple domains (multiple certs) on Haproxy

Tags: ssl-certificate, load-balancing, haproxy

Let's say that we have haproxy in front of 2 apache:

```
                     +----> Apache (10.0.0.2)
Haproxy (10.0.0.1) --|
                     +----> Apache (10.0.0.3)
```

- Haproxy is configured to load balance traffic based on URI (needs to see URI so have to see content of HTTP)
- Apache is hosting a large amount of domains
- Every domain is accessible in HTTPS via haproxy that offloads SSL and initiate HTTP connection to Apache
- Every domain has its own SSL certificate (no SAN or wildcard cert)

I saw that Haproxy allows us to give a directory with many certificates but I didn't manage to make it work with another thing that a single certificate.

Here is my (simplified) configuration:

```
global
        [...]
        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

        # For backends connections
        ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3
        ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

frontend https_frontend
        bind 10.0.0.1:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mycerts/mydomain.pem # HERE WE WANT A DIRECTORY INSTEAD OF A FILE
        default_backend apache_backend

backend apache_backend
        cookie SRVID insert indirect nocache

        # Backends
        server apache1 10.0.0.2:80 check maxconn 64
        server apache2 10.0.0.3:80 check maxconn 64

        # Load Balancing - URI Consistent
        balance uri
        hash-type consistent

        # Options
        option http-keep-alive
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `crt-list` and point to a file containing the list of certificates, so your frontend would read as

```
frontend https_frontend
    bind 10.0.0.1:443 ssl crt-list /etc/ssl/private/mycerts.txt
    default_backend apache_backend
```

And to generate the list just with something like `find /etc/ssl/private/mycerts/ > /etc/ssl/private/mycerts.txt`. See more information in https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#5.1-crt-list

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and it worked well, but it obliges me to know every domain that has a certificate. Is there no other way to do this without listing certificates?